# How do you "stick" images on the side of the website, and align text to that image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to make a website that looks like this:

[image: Website mockup]

But I am having difficulties "sticking" the image on the side of the website so that when you change the screen-width, the image will follow.

I am also having problems with aligning the content with the center of the image.

I am using flexbox since it is the easiest with responsive design.

```css
/*
    flex-column is should activate through a media query after 700px,
    therefore I set max width-700px
*/

    .flex-column{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        max-width: 700px;
    }
  
    flex-row{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
```

```html
<!--flex-column to make all the divs go under eachother  -->
    <div class="flex-column">
       
<!--1st flex-item-->

        <div class="flex-item">
<!--           I tired to use flex-row to align img and content horizontally-->
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum temporibus nam porro eaque corrupti perferendis enim blanditiis voluptatem molestias perspiciatis fuga facilis suscipit ullam asperiores esse velit minima, earum totam sint quibusdam numquam, doloremque ab provident. Exercitationem 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--2nd-flexitem-->

        <div class="flex-item">
<!--           I tired to use flex-row to align img and content horizontally-->
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"  height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum aspernatur non unde repellat molestias eligendi, earum dolore tenetur, nisi eos modi quas sapiente repudiandae exercitationem quaerat ea doloremque possimus vel ipsa doloribus soluta. Veniam voluptas officia laudantium qui cum magnam
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
<!--3rd-flexitem-->

        <div class="flex-item">
<!--           I tired to use flex-row to align img and content horizontally-->
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem molestiae quas consequatur unde reiciendis saepe, ex hic minima molestias mollitia dolorem cumque dignissimos, debitis, enim soluta repellendus atque ullam qui porro aspernatur! Eaque cupiditate, at magnam aliquam obcaecati 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hava a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At the moment I don't see a question in your "question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have an error in your CSS section: `flex-row{`
instead of: `.flex-row{`.

With these lines it should work for you:

```
.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}    

.flex-item:nth-child(even) .flex-row{
      flex-direction: row-reverse;

  }
}
```

Next time please put it into a fiddle - it would be easier to work with - Here's your code after those edits: https://jsfiddle.net/v3zepwLz/3/

```css
.flex-column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 700px;
}

.flex-row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}    

.flex-item:nth-child(even) .flex-row{
      flex-direction: row-reverse;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<!--flex-column to make all the divs go under eachother  -->
    <div class="flex-column">
       
<!--1st flex-item-->

        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum temporibus nam porro eaque corrupti perferendis enim blanditiis voluptatem molestias perspiciatis fuga facilis suscipit ullam asperiores esse velit minima, earum totam sint quibusdam numquam, doloremque ab provident. Exercitationem 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<!--2nd-flexitem-->

        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"  height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum aspernatur non unde repellat molestias eligendi, earum dolore tenetur, nisi eos modi quas sapiente repudiandae exercitationem quaerat ea doloremque possimus vel ipsa doloribus soluta. Veniam voluptas officia laudantium qui cum magnam
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
<!--3rd-flexitem-->

        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="flex-row">
                <div class="image-wrap">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"   height="120" width="120" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem molestiae quas consequatur unde reiciendis saepe, ex hic minima molestias mollitia dolorem cumque dignissimos, debitis, enim soluta repellendus atque ullam qui porro aspernatur! Eaque cupiditate, at magnam aliquam obcaecati 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Picard. I will remember that next time, thank you